# How to check DB connections and make reconnect in case of need?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, hikaricp

I have an application that connects to the DB using scan address. There are two identical Oracle instances of DB under this scan address. If one instance is down for some reason or crashes the app should recover automatically and try to connect to the other working instance of the DB.

I use HikariCP, Hibernate, jdbc:thin client and Oracle DB.

Which of these I should force to check if the connection to the DB is alive and if it's not try to establish new one?

The scan address above the two database instances works fine. When my app crashes and I refresh the page it automatically creates a pool of connections on the other working DB, but I need this process to be done automatically.

I use Hikari xml configuration:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize:0}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize:10}" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${jdbc.maxIdleTimeSeconds:10000}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: This will happen automatically, *if* you only obtain connections for a unit-of-work and return it to the pool as soon as you're done. The pool will validate connections before handing them out, and if the connection is no longer valid, it will be tossed out and replaced. The only part where you need to be prepared to handle errors is that a failover in the middle of using a connection will require you to retry the entire unit-of-work (including obtaining the connection).

Comment: In any case, you may want to update your question with a [mre] and details.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Its very hard to update the question - the app is very huge and the only thing I mess up with right now is the Hikari library. It's true that the application ended up with error only when I actively used it. When I just started it and let it run without any tasks running and stoped the DB, the application didn't complain at all. After that when I clicked on some other tab or menu everything worked fine and the connections were estabilished with the other DB instance. How to take care about the failover? Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

There are various thing to consider:

- HikariCP checks every connection before borrowing it to application. Unless there is a delay less that 10 seconds between borrows.
- Oracle's JDBC drivers implement functionality: Application Continuity(AC). JDBC drivers remembers inserts/updates sent to a database, when transaction is open. When you loose this connection, JDBC driver transparently re-connects and replays SQLs. This feature has some limitations, but in basic situations data is not lost even in situations when transaction is not COMMITed yet.
- Oracle introduced few handy features in JDBC 4.x standards. One of them is `Connection.isValid()`. On Oracle's case is does the same thing as OCIPing. It exchanges a single packet roundtrip between Application and DB server. Having a particular SQL to be executed on each Connection borrow belongs to past - there are better ways today.
- Just execute your JDBC driver and it will tell you when JDBC version it supports.

  ```
  $ java -jar ojdbc8.jar
  Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_91 on Tue_Dec_13_06:08:31_PST_2016
  #Default Connection Properties Resource
  #Mon Jun 10 20:13:17 CEST 2019
  ```
- Aside from HikariCP you can also use Oracle's UCP. This connection pooling library implementation can receive events from RAC cluster, can load balance connections between nodes. can close connection to a particular db node when requested. You can even have zero-downtime DB server patching, when configured properly.